# Shapes.AddPicture method picture auto width keeping fixed height

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that places fixed height and fixed width pictures in cells.

How to modify this VBA to place pictures - auto width in fixed height (80.5) by keeping the original aspect ratio, using this example from Excel Shapes.AddPicture method?

```
Sub URLPicturesInsert()
    
    Dim Rng As Range, cell As Range, filename As String
    Dim Pshp As Shape
    Dim aUrls() As String
    Dim i As Long
    
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("G2:G5")
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    For Each cell In Rng
        
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            aUrls = Split(cell.Value, "|")
            
            For i = LBound(aUrls) To UBound(aUrls)
                filename = Trim(aUrls(i))
                
                ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture _
                filename:=filename, _
                LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
                SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
                Left:=cell.Left + (i * 80.5), _
                Top:=cell.Top, _
                Width:=80.5, _
                Height:=80.5
    
            Next i
            
            cell.EntireRow.RowHeight = 80.5
            
            cell.Value = ""
            
        End If
        
        
    Next cell

Range("G2").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Process completed successfully", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Shape.ScaleHeight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.scaleheight).

The `factor` is 80.5 divided by its current height. `RelativeToOriginalSize` is false, since we're scaling based on its current height, not its original height. `Scale` can be any of the [options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msoscalefrom) based on how it best fits your needs.

An example:

```vb
With Sheet1.Shapes("Picture 1")
    .ScaleHeight 80.5 / .Height, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
End With
```

For your code:

```vb
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture( _
        fileName:=fileName, _
        LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
        SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
        Left:=Cell.Left + (i * 80.5), _
        top:=Cell.top, _
        Width:=-1, _
        Height:=-1 _
    )
        .ScaleHeight 80.5 / .Height, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    End With
```